# "Optimizely" for Magento2

Tags: magento2, optimization

Can anyone guide me for installing **Optimizely** for Magento2?

The client has installed it for Magento1 but can anyone tell it supports Magento2 as he wants Optimizely only(not any other similar one).

Answer (score 1):

To start running A/B tests on your site, you'll need to add a small snippet of code to the  tag of your site's code. This snippet contains your unique Project ID, and it allows the experiments you create in Optimizely to execute on your site.

You can add the script in Magento backend configuration misc HTML section.

Comment: can you share that snippet code with us?

Comment: <script src="https://cdn.optimizely.com/js/10444771869.js"></script>

Comment: Thanks for the info but does it works for AB testing?